# Xmonad is not changing layouts

Tags: xmonad

You can change layouts in `Xmonad` with <kbd>mod+space</kbd> [or](http://haskell.org/wikiupload/b/b8/Xmbindings.png) switch windows (in fullscreen) with <kbd>mod+tab</kbd>.

I encounter everyday the problem that these bindings stop working (I don't know what causes it). I'm able to change workspaces with <kbd>mod+1 | 2 | ... | 9</kbd> and this problem occurs usually only in one workspace. I tried to solve it with moving all the windows from the workspace (where it stopped working) to another workspace but this didn't help.
I solve it with logging out and logging in. Is there some way to solve it without logging out?

Comment: Did you try reloading xmonad without logging out, with <kbd>mod+Q</kbd>? Does the problem persist if you do this?

Comment: Also, if the problem persists, it might help if you posted your `xmonad.hs` which might help determine its cause.

Comment: @Dalker I can try it as soon as this problem occurs again, but it's not the best solution because after reloading some applications defined in `xmonad.hs` automatically launch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *could* be you <kbd>mod+left mouse button drag</kbd>ed  a window in master -- this will *float the window* and cause the symptoms you described.  (The layout actually changes, **behind** the window.)
<kbd>mod+t</kbd> should unfloat the window.

Comment: Maybe I exaggerated that this occurs every day (but there are times it happens twice a day, it depends on what I'm doing and intensity of work). I'm waiting for it since I asked this question. When it will happen I will try your advice.

Comment: Actually, you can *test* if the problem is what I described.  Just press `mod` and mouse-drag a window, see if this is the issue.

Comment: Yes, this caused the same problem and <kbd>mod+t</kbd> solved it. However, I'm not sure if I was dragging windows before. It's possible that in my case this happened another way. I will accept it, but when <kbd>mod+t</kbd> won't solve it, I will reopen.

Comment: Now, I can confirm that your solution works (I wasn't dragging anothing) and mod+t helped again.

Comment: Something akin to `float` in your `xmonad.hs`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you've pressed mod-comma or mod-period and changed the number of windows in the master pane. The default is to have one window in the master pane. If you then press mod-period, you reduce that to zero, which would essentially change Tall mode to Wide mode when there are only two windows open. You can also get into a similar situation if you press mod-comma and increase the number of windows in the master pane up to the number of windows being displayed. This setting is remembered per-workspace and per-layout on that workspace.

To reset the layout to the default configuration for a given workspace, you can press mod-shift-space.